# Task "typescript" failed in grunt

Tags: gruntjs, typescript

I have written below code in gruntFile.js.

```
typescript: {
            base: {
                options: {
                    target: 'es5',
                    sourceMap: true,
                    noImplicitAny: true
                }
            },
            default: {
                files: [
                  { src: 'source/tests/**/*.ts', dest: 'build'},
                  { src: 'source/scripts/**/*.ts', dest: 'build'}
                ]
            }
        },
```

and I am trying to run "**grunt typescript**" command from command line. It is showing below error.

[image]

I have tryed "**grunt typescript --force**" command also. but still it is not working.
[image]

still it is not create build folder and it means that task is not working properly. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:-**  I have change my gruntfile.js to below as suggest in answer.

```
typescript: {
            base: {
                src: ['source/tests/**/*.ts'],
                dest: 'build/',
                options: {
                    target: 'es5',
                    sourceMap: true,
                    noImplicitAny: true
                }
            },
}
```

But still I am facing same problem.

Comment: Which `grunt-typescript` package are you using for the compilation?

Comment: I am using "grunt-typescript": "^0.6.1".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the most current [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-typescript) that I could find for `grunt-typescript`, your syntax is wrong. I have a feeling that you actually want to be using [grunt-ts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-ts). It's  also the plugin I know of that is compatible with the syntax you've supplied.

My personal opinion: Use grunt-ts, it's been *much* easier to work with, and I've gone through a few iterations of trying out a bunch of tools to get to our current build environment.

Comment: I have changed my gruntfile.js to below. But still getting same error.
  typescript: {
            base: {
                src: ['source/tests/**/*.ts'],
                dest: 'build',
                options: {
                    target: 'es5',
                    sourceMap: true,
                    noImplicitAny: true
                }
            }

Comment: @SBI-  It is not any sytax error. But still i have changed GrantFile.js as you have suggested. See my updated question. thanks.

Comment: It's a good idea to use verbose output when possible, you need all the debugging info you can get.

Comment: Actually there is no error in syntax . simply I have removed grunt and reinstall again and it is solve the problem. thanks.